# Couldn't execute "fastboot" commands on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, android, bootloader

I try to use android-tools/fastboot commands like

```
fastboot devices
```

Then I get the error message

```
fastboot: symbol lookup error: fastboot: undefined symbol: _ZN13TemporaryFileD1Ev
```

I try two way to install:

```
sudo apt install fastboot
```

and

```
sudo apt install android-tools-fastboot
```

Error message is the same for both.

Here is some outputs:

```
pm@dev:~$ which fastboot
/usr/bin/fastboot

pm@dev:~$ dpkg -S /usr/bin/fastboot
fastboot: /usr/bin/fastboot

pm@dev:~$ ldd /usr/bin/fastboot
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffca6dbb000)
    libziparchive.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libziparchive.so.0 (0x00007f097209d000)
    libsparse.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libsparse.so.0 (0x00007f0971e95000)
    libbase.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbase.so.0 (0x00007f0971c8b000)
    libcutils.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libcutils.so.0 (0x00007f0971a7f000)
    libadb.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libadb.so.0 (0x00007f097184e000)
    libutils.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libutils.so.0 (0x00007f097162c000)
    libf2fs_utils.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libf2fs_utils.so.0 (0x00007f0971429000)
    libstdc++.so.6 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6 (0x00007f09710a0000)
    libgcc_s.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgcc_s.so.1 (0x00007f0970e88000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007f0970a97000)
    libz.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libz.so.1 (0x00007f097087a000)
    liblog.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/liblog.so.0 (0x00007f0970673000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007f0970454000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007f0970011000)
    libbacktrace.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libbacktrace.so.0 (0x00007f096fdf5000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007f096fbf1000)
    libm.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0x00007f096f853000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007f09724c7000)
    libunwind.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libunwind.so.0 (0x00007f096f60a000)
    lib7z.so => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/lib7z.so (0x00007f096f219000)
```

Comment: How did you installed FastBoot? Please add output of `which fastboot`, `dpkg -S $(which fastboot)` and `ldd $(which fastboot)` to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please ensure that you have installed all updates and that your repositories are correctly set (you have all pockets *main*, *universe*, *multiverse* and *restricted* with all updates enabled *bionic-updates*, *bionic-security*). If unsure [check this](https://askubuntu.com/a/192388/66509).

Then run:

```
sudo apt-get update # to update package lists
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade # to get newest dependencies
```

I can't reproduce your issue on clean installed and fully-updated Ubuntu 18.04 LTS.

The `ldd`'s output differs from yours by a few of lines (addresses removed to be more clear):

> ```
> ...
> libcrypto.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libcrypto.so.0
> libcrypto_utils.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/android/libcrypto_utils.so.0
> libusb-1.0.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libusb-1.0.so.0
> libudev.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libudev.so.1
> librt.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/librt.so.1
> ...
> ```

and from basing on these differences I'll recommend to install the following packages:

```
sudo apt-get install android-libboringssl android-libcrypto-utils libudev1 libusb-1.0-0
```

and retry.

Comment: My **ldd** output has become the same as yours after executing **sudo apt-get dist-upgrade**. The error message does not appear now. Thanks for your help @N0rbert

Comment: PS: now **fastboot** doesn't recognize my devices, but **adb** does. I may open another topic for this. :)

Answer (score 2):

I ran into this too, getting

```
fastboot: symbol lookup error: fastboot: undefined symbol: _ZN13TemporaryFileD1Ev
```

The problem in my case was an older `adb` package, which I installed about a year ago.
Upgrading this and the companion `android-libadb`

```
apt-get install adb android-libadb
```

to the newest version solved the issue for me.

---

apt-get installed and updated a whole bunch of other packages as well. Investigating further shows, that the relevant symbol is provided by `libbase.so.0`, which in turn can be updated by

```
apt-get install android-libbase
```

I haven't tested, if this alone is sufficient, but you might get away with it.

Comment: My packages were already up-to-date. Thanks for your help.